# 504 Gateway Timeout for Azure ASP.NET Core 8 app deployed on linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-8.0, asp.net-core-8

I have a long-running Razor page. I am getting the following response after about 4 minutes:

> 504.0 GatewayTimeout

I have tried the information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/timeouts?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

I've updated my start up code with

```
builder.Services.AddRequestTimeouts();
```

and

```
app.UseRouting();
```

I've used the [`RequestTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.timeouts.requesttimeoutattribute?view=aspnetcore-8.0) attribute specifying a time, I've used it with a policy, and I've also tried the [`DisableRequestTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.timeouts.disablerequesttimeoutattribute?view=aspnetcore-8.0) attribute. I've tried these attributes at the page (class) level as well as on the endpoint (method). Nothing seems to have any effect.

What am I missing?

Comment: 1) Please show how exactly you configure the timeouts 2) Note that reverse proxy or something else between your app and end user can have timeout set up too.

Comment: Also from the linked doc - _"Apps can apply timeout limits selectively to requests. ASP.NET Core servers don't do this by default since request processing times vary widely by scenario."_. So `AddRequestTimeouts` if I understand correctly can only make things worse.

Comment: Would you kindly double check that the middleware for handling timeouts is in the correct order. Because the order of middleware matters, and the timeout middleware should be configured before the middleware that processes the request. It should be like `app.UseRequestTimeout();
app.UseRouting();.`, In addition, do you have log details?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron The docs say the opposite, that UseRequestTimeout() should be called *after* UseRouting();

Comment: Does changing order in either way has any impact? Does the error has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Azure to host your application? I had the exact same problem, I tried everything, including pulling out some of what's left of my hair, until I finally found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-performance-faqs#why-does-my-request-time-out-after-230-seconds
It can't be overridden...